# How to pass linebreak from a variable in "ANSI-C" way?

Tags: bash, variable, newlines

If I run this code

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -x

http --json http://example.com \
    value=$'hello\r\n\r\nworld'
```

I have in the stdout the two carriage return I have inside `value`

```
http --json http://example.com 'value=hello

world'
```

But if I have the `value` string inside a variable, I do not find a way to obtain the same in the stdout. In example if I run

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -x

variable="hello\r\n\r\nworld"

http --json http://example.com \
    value=$''"$variable"''
```

I have not the linebreaks but `\r\n\r\n` chars

```
http --json http://example.com 'value=hello\r\n\r\nworld'
```

How to have the linebreaks starting from value inside a variable?

I cannot change `variable="hello\r\n\r\nworld"`, but I can add code between it and the run of the command.

Comment: Why not `variable=$'hello\nworld'` and then `http ... value="$variable"`? Note that `$''` is an empty string.  Not posting this as an answer as I don't know what the `http` utility is.

Comment: @Kusalananda It works, thank you, but I cannot change `variable="hello\r\n\r\nworld"` (it's a problem by design). Could I add a second variable to transform `variable` in `$'hello\r\n\r\nworld'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way for me it's

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

variable="hello\r\n\r\nworld"

http --json http://example.com \
    value="${variable@E}"
```

Comment: Oo, I'd forgotten about `@E`. It only works in Bash, but it does fit this case rather nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `$'...'` in the variable assignment, as in

```
variable=$'hello\r\n\r\nworld'
```

instead of

```
variable="hello\r\n\r\nworld"
```

Or use `printf` to process the escapes (this should work in any POSIXy shell):

```
escaped="hello\r\n\r\nworld"
raw=$(printf "%b" "$escaped")
```

Though note that command substitution would eat the final newline(s) if there are any, so you may have to work around that by adding and removing a dummy character at the end:

```
escaped="hello world\n"
raw=$(printf "%b." "$escaped")
raw=${raw%.}
```

Then use the resulting variable as usual.